# Creating & Using Custom Controllers trailhead

Tags: apex, visualforce, page-layout

My code is working but when i check the challenge it still has error. please help.

This is my apex class

```
 public class NewCaseListController {
    public static List <Case> getNewCases(){
    List<Case> q = [Select Id, caseNumber FROM Case Where Status = 'New'];
        return q; 
        }
 }
```

This is my vf code

```
 <apex:page controller="NewCaseListController">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock title="Case List" >
        <apex:repeat value="{! NewCases}" var="case">
            <li>><apex:outputLink value="{! URLFOR($Action.Case.View, case.Id)}" >{! case.caseNumber}   
                </apex:outputLink>   </li> 
            </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
```

this is the error

[image]

Comment: I am not sure how its working at your end `List<Case> q = [Select Id, caseNumber FROM Case Where Status = 'New'];`. I see the error `line 4:0 no viable alternative at character ' ' in Visual Force`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everything is looking correct. Please make sure you have case records in your org if they are not there. Create some cases in your getNewCases property.

remove static keyword as well.

Comment: I have removed the static then comes this new error The outputLink component is not binding to the ID of a case

Comment: there is no need to define urlfor in outputlink if you will simply bind. case.id with it, it will work

Comment: fantastic... :)

Comment: upvote and close this question. you have another question open close that too.

Answer (score -1):

### page

```xml
<apex:page controller="NewCaseListController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock title="Case List" >
            <apex:repeat value="{! getNewCases}" var="case">
                <li>><apex:outputLink value="/{!case.Id}" >
                {! case.caseNumber}   
                </apex:outputLink></li> 
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

### class

```java
public class NewCaseListController {
    public List<Case> getNewCases() {
        List<Case> q = [Select Id, caseNumber FROM Case Where Status = 'New'];
        return q; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Trailhead challenge completed successfully for this code.

Comment: To improve your answer an explanation on how this is different to and what the problem in the askers code was would be nice.